# Can I just get rid of Windows altogether?

Tags: software-installation, windows-8, format, restart

I tried to do a dual boot but I can't get into Ubuntu. Can I just wipe everything out and just load Ubuntu? I have a Sony VAIO laptop. I don't really need Windows for anything do I? would I have to format and then install from USB?

Comment: Sure, if that's what you want to do. Just boot the installer from USB and choose "use entire drive for Ubuntu," and it will re-partition your drive, format it, and install Ubuntu, erasing all existing data.

Comment: I highly recommend this! But if there is any data, anything at all, that you want to keep from your Windows installation, back it up somewhere off that computer first.

Comment: Remember to preserve your Windows Product Key (there are several ways - look it up) in case you someday want to reinstall Windows on this hardware again. Five minutes now will save you hundreds of dollars later.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Comment: "I don't really need Windows for anything do I?" – That depends on what you want to do with your computer which we don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can not decide this for you but there is a method where you can have both with just using Ubuntu as your single operating system:

- Install Ubuntu
- Install either virtualbox or vmplayer
- Install Windows inside virtualbox/vmplayer.

It looks like this:

[image]

Do not forget to backup data you need to keep.

Comment: Qemu/(KVM or Spice) is another option for virtual machines.